# linux server hard drives raid 0

Tags: server, raid

I have a question about my hard drives configuration on my linux server build on server. I have 2 x 3TB hard drives attached to it, but they are configured as RAID 1 at the moment. So the data is being synced on the 2 drives. I would like to configure it as RAID 0 so the 2 drives are separated. Do you have any tips for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, if you change to RAID 0, you would need to create the array again, which means you would lose all your data. I think it's important to be aware of the risks involved with RAID 0 though. There is an increased risk of array, or drive failure resulting in complete and total data loss on the RAID 0 array.

If you are determined to use RAID 0, creating the array depends on what kind of RAID controller you are using, along with the type of server you are using. Assuming the RAID controller is built into the motherboard, it should be possible to enter a RAID configuration menu in the initial stages of the computer booting. Which key you need to press depends on the controller type.
What type of RAID controller does your system use?
To see if you have a Hardware RAID, run:

```
lspci | grep -i raid
```

Software RAID:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Also, who is the vendor for your server?

Comment: cat /proc/mdstat gives me:Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      1073610560 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sdb4[1] sda4[0]
      1847478528 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      523968 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      8384448 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>

Answer (score 0):

Pragmatically:

1. Back up all your data to an external harddrive.
2. Destroy your raid array.
3. When you recreate your raid array, use the XFS file system, ESPECIALLY if you are using this for large files. If not XFS, use EXT4. BTRFS is not a performance filesystem, and raid support is still in its infancy. Also, the developers of BTRFS outright say that XFS is the best performer on RAID arrays.

So there is your secret tip; >**XFS**<

Comment: How do i destroy my raid array? I don't have any data yet so thats is no problem to lose it.

Comment: @user313020 Good question; in fact; after this, you should make an account and ask it in "Ask Ubuntu". Short answer: It depends what kind of raid you have: http://superuser.com/a/313437 << This shows the three types of raid. For Onboard Raid, you will find the configuration at bootup, either in the bios or right after it. For hardware raid... well you will have to consult the manufacturer for that. For software raid; this tutorial shows how to setup and **delete** using the linux software raid tool MDADM http://www.mysolutions.it/tutorial-mdadm-software-raid-ubuntu-debian-systems/